# OneNote extension for spaced repetition learning

Tags: microsoft-onenote, spaced-repetition

I use OneNote to take notes when studying. I would like to use a spaced repetition system to help me review my notes effectively. I could use a standalone spaced repetition application such as [Anki](http://ankisrs.net/), but a workflow with two separate applications is not convenient:

- When I add new notes to OneNote, I must manually copy-paste them to the spaced repetition system (SRS).
- If I edit my notes in OneNote to add detail or correct mistakes, I have to manually move those changes to the SRS.
- My notes in OneNote are organized by sections. I need to manually recreate this organization in the SRS.

Is there a OneNote extension for reviewing OneNote notes using the spaced repetition method?

Comment: I've submitted this question in [OneNote's subreddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/OneNote/comments/ckroiy/onenote_extension_for_spaced_repetition_learning/). Hope there are more people can answer this